# Error in coding

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

i want to prompt error if the value is greater. error showed through msgbox but the problem which i am facing is to perform further task after click on "OKAY", my coding is shown below please help me out as docmd is not working and i want to close form after click on "OKAY"

Coding:-

```
Function Tokenincrease()

  Dim Test As String
  Test = MsgBox(" One Day One Token", vbExclamation + vbokayonly, "Sorry")
  If Test = vbOK Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Token Isuance Form LH"
  Else
      DoCmd.Close
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: i have created a application when through which we are issuing daily tokens. our management has a wish that only one token should be issued in a day. so if the person come for 2nd time the system prompt the message and than i want to close the form which is running. for that i have wrote the coding in MODULE, message appears  when entering for the 2nd time but after click on "Okay " button system prompt error on DOCMD.Close.

Comment: @MUR, are you sure that this question shouldn't be tagged [`vba`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) or [`access-vba`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/access-vba/info)? VB.Net and VBScript are two very different languages, and your code snippet doesn't look either of those two languages.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will no close the form when the user clicks "OKAY" because you if states:

```
If Test = vbOK
```

which means if will then execute the OpenForm. To close the form, which I assume you mean you want to execute DoCmd.Close, then you want

```
If Test <> vbOK
```

Looking at the tags to this question this is related to VB.NET. If this is correct, then there are better ways to open/close forms and there is also a dedicated MessageBox class. It is recommended that you use these as the code you have looks a lot like VBScript/Office/Access code.

EDIT 1: Instead of using vbOK use OK or 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=VS.80).aspx.

Comment: Now i have changed the coding, but still its not working, when i click on Okay the with still show open. below coding   

Function Tokenincrease()

Dim Test As String


 Test = MsgBox(" One Day One Token", vbExclamation + vbOK, "Sorry")
 
 
 If Test <> vbOK Then
 
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "Issuance Display Form Lunch", acSaveYes
 
 
 
 
 End If
 
  
   
End Function

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get `vbOKOnly` and you have it as vbokayonly

It should really look like this:

```
 Function Tokenincrease()

  If MsgBox("One Day One Token", vbExclamation & vbokonly, "Sorry") = vbOK Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Token Isuance Form LH"
  Else
      DoCmd.Close
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Dear Logixologist

Run Time Error '5'
Invalid Procedure call or argument

Comment: I was on my Mac and I didnt have Visual Studio up..  let me look at it and let you know in a few.

Comment: I just edited it, try again... basicaly you needed an "&" to combine options in the message box

Comment: Actually to @motosv's point, you have it in reverse. It should be <> vbok then show the form, else close the form

Answer (score 0):

Change like this ..

```
Function Tokenincrease()

  Dim Test As MsgBoxResult
  Test = MsgBox(" One Day One Token", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Sorry")
  If Test = MsgBoxResult.OK Then

       DoCmd.Close         

  End If
End Function
```